# Determining $\gcd(n^2+100, n^2+2n+101)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, proof-explanation, gcd-and-lcm

How would you determine an $n$ value given:
$$\gcd(n^2+100,n^2+2n+101)$$

I found the solution off a website, and I don't understand anything past the first step, found in solution 4:

https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/1985_AIME_Problems/Problem_13#Solution_4

Could someone please explain?

SOLVED: How to close thread?

Comment: "SOLVED: How to close thread?" : No reason to "close" thread.  In fact, go ahead and **answer your own question**.  You can either add it your analysis as an *answer* if the interface permits, or you can edit your query to provide the analysis directly in your query.  Assuming that you do this, and others read it, they might (for example) provide interesting alternative methods of solution.

Comment: Alright. I'll post it soon then.

Comment: My calculations indicate that as ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, $\langle x^2 + 100, x^2 + 2x + 101 \rangle = \langle x+201, 401 \rangle$.  Therefore, for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, we have $\gcd(n^2 + 100, n^2 + 2n + 101) = \gcd(n + 201, 401)$.  (And 401 happens to be prime.)